# How to customize the border for MUI components

Tags: reactjs

How can I change the border properties for an MUI Select component using `ThemeProvider`? I'm able to change the `backgroundColor`, but for some reason border properties like `border` and `borderColor` do not work.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  ThemeProvider,
  Box,
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
  MenuItem,
  Select,
} from "@mui/material";
import theme from "./theme";

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Box sx={{ minWidth: 200, margin: "5%" }}>
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Select Label</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
            id="demo-simple-select"
            label="Select Label"
            variant="outlined"
            sx={{ minWidth: 200 }}
          >
            <MenuItem value={"1"}>Item 1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={"2"}>Item 2</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={"3"}>Item 3</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**theme.js**

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";

const darkGrey = "#262626";
const mediumGrey = "#595959";
const lightGrey = "#adadad";
const white = "#ffffff";
const limeGreen = "3df730";

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiSelect: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: mediumGrey,
          border: "4px",
          borderColor: "red",
        },
      },
    },
    // This doesn't work either
    // MuiOutlinedInput: {
    //   styleOverrides: {
    //     root: {
    //       border: "4px",
    //       borderColor: limeGreen,
    //     },
    //   },
    // },
    MuiInputLabel: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          color: white,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three main issues here:

First, the `styleOverrides` of the `Select` component do not have any `root` property (see https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/#css). You can use `select` instead.

Second, your border doesn't have any specified thickness so it won't be visible.

Third, your `limeGreen` color doesn't start with a `#` so it won't be recognized as a hex color.

Here is a fixed version of the styling file:

```js
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material';

const darkGrey = '#262626';
const mediumGrey = '#595959';
const lightGrey = '#adadad';
const white = '#ffffff';
const limeGreen = '#3df730';

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiSelect: {
      styleOverrides: {
        select: {
          backgroundColor: mediumGrey,
          border: 'solid 3px',
          borderColor: limeGreen,
        },
      },
    },
    // This doesn't work either
    // MuiOutlinedInput: {
    //   styleOverrides: {
    //     root: {
    //       border: "4px",
    //       borderColor: limeGreen,
    //     },
    //   },
    // },
    MuiInputLabel: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          color: white,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```